# Drools: can we add/amends rules at runtime

Tags: runtime, drools, rule-engine

can we add/amends rules (.drl or decision table) at runtime in drools ?

For example
I created a simple decision table rule, this rule worked fined, however any change in decision table was not reflected in rule evaluation at runtime until the jvm was restarted.

Tried this re-creating the KieSession

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by creating new KieSession instance as below:

```java
This was done with 
drools version: 8.32.0 
java 11
============================

KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    builder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(<rule xls file directory>), ResourceType.DTABLE);
    InternalKnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    knowledgeBase.addPackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());
    knowledgeBase.newKieSession();
=====================
```

The new session was created whenever there was any amend made in the rule.